# Asp.net add form onsubmit() from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I modify the onsubmit parameter of a form from a master page asp.net project in the code behind of a child page?

I would like to update the form value to be something like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="SetPostbackValues()">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below -

```
((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm) Master.FindControl("form1")).Attributes.Add("onsubmit",
            "javascript:return SetPostbackValues();");
```